# Redirect to mobile version, respecting domain, with htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mobile

I have a site which has multiple domains, ie:

```
www.site.co.uk
www.site.ru
www.site-german.de
```

And the mobile version is in  `/mobile/`

How can I redirect from the current domain to `/mobile/` path?

I believe I need to check if the domain is one of the listed and the current path is not mobile, right? ( I am really bad with regular expressions.. )

This is what I have for now:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/mobile/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Which works, but as you can see it doesn't check if the current path is '/mobile/' and it doesn't check for the other domains..

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe by adding a `RewriteCond` to check the current path, with a **negative regex group** `(?!...)`, as :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "ipod|iphone|ipad|android|palm|blackberry|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/mobile/)
RewriteRule ^(.*)  /mobile/$1   [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: thanks for you answer! seems to work but some images wont resolve properly, any idea why?

Comment: Check that asset path are correct (relative / absolute problem cause redirection) in generated html source code.

Comment: In this case, you should try disable rewriterule for image files, by adding a `RewriteCond` like : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(jpg|gif)$`

Comment: So I just add it before te rewriteRule?

Comment: yes, try add this directive before the rewriteRule directive (and don't forget to adapt file extension pattern for your own needs)

Comment: it doesn't seem to help, under the mobile version some imgs are broken, but if I remove the .htaccess code block, and enter to the mobile version manually, it works

Comment: Hum, in your URL, RewriteRule makes a rewrite or a redirect (you see or not /mobile/) ?

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(?!/mobile/inc/) solved, this where dynamic generated images, thanks!!!